# How do you say opinion in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english

I always translated it as 'думка' until I wanted to say 'I don't have an opinion' in Ukrainian. Now, that translates as 'У мене немає думки', which seems to me like I'm saying I have no thoughts about it at all. But what if I happen to know quite a few facts about something, but I just haven't formed an opinion? Is there a more precise word for an opinion that I can use?

Comment: I would say "думка" is perfectly fine in 'У мене немає думки' context. It may sound like "I have no thoughts" but still in that context people will understand 'I don't have an opinion'. It's rather "Я не маю жодної гадки" eq to "I have no thoughts/idea". You also may try "полгяд" (view) i.e. "Я не маю на це погляду".

Answer (score 8):

A few more translations of the sentence 'I don't have an opinion' [about/on it]:

- Я не маю (чіткої) **позиції** [щодо цього].
- Я ще не сформував *позиції* [щодо цього].
- У мене ще не сформована *позиція* [щодо цього].
- Я ще не сформував (чіткої) **думки** [щодо цього].
- У мене ще не сформована *думка* [щодо цього].
- Я ще не маю *думки* [щодо цього].
- Я ще не сформував **погляду** [на це].
- Я ще не маю *погляду* [на це].
- Мій *погляд* [на це] ще не сформований.
- Я ще про це так **ґрунтовно не думав**.
- Я поки **невпевнений, що я думаю** з цього приводу.

You can also use "**опінія**" (a directly borrowed word):

- У мене ще не сформована *опінія* [щодо цього].
- Я ще не маю своєї *опінії* [щодо цього].
- Я ще не сформував своєї *опінії* [з цього приводу].

Answer (score 4):

Note:  *Не маю на думці* or *не маю думки* is better than *у мене немає думки*, because it's:

- a little shorter, even with *я*;
- a literal translation;
- a [root](/a/1161/585);
- recorded [in a dictionary](http://sum.in.ua/s/dumka):

> *Мати (є, було) на думці* — думати про кого-, що-небудь.
>
> ---
>
> (literal) *To have (be, was/were) on thought* — to think about somebody/thing.

Here is a [newer dictionary](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50106):

> (53) **Ма́ти ду́мку** (**га́дку**, **на ду́мці**, *рідше* **на га́дці** *і т. ін.*):
>
> а) *(про що)* думати про що-небудь, розмірковувати над чимсь.
>
> *Скажи мені, серце моє, що маєш на гадці* (П. Чубинський); *Він ще тоді добре втямив, .. що небезпечно говорити те, що думає чоловік, що має на мислі...* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *А тут ніхто, навіть мої хлопці не знають, що я за гадку маю* (І. Франко); *– Робіть так, аби моїм дітям кривди не було, бо я маю таку гадку, що відси я вже не годен вийти* (В. Стефаник); *З ранку до вечора залюбки розповідав би їй про все, що мав на думці* (І. Муратов);

And as you can read next, there is also:

> ***Не мати (не було) на (в) думці*** — не думати про що-небудь, не допускати чогось, не мати наміру що-небудь робити.
>
> ---
>
> (literal) *To do not have (wasn't) on (in) thought* — to do not think about something, to do not suppose, to do not have intention to do something.

So, you can use this if you were asked this question:

> — Що думаєш? / Що маєш на думці?
> — Не маю нічого на думці. / Жодної думки.
>
> ---
>
> — What do you think (about)? / Do you have opinion?
> — I donʼt have any opinion. / No any thought.

An example of using with the verb *know* from [Oleksij Longhvinenko](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleksiy_Logvynenko)ʼs translation for [The Catcher in the Rye](//www.ukrlib.com.ua/world/printit.php?tid=133&page=2) (J. D. Salinger):

> Ви скажете, що негарно так говорити про старих людей, я знаю, але я не маю на думці нічого негарного.

But, yeah, rarely it could be defined as 'you know nothing', but it is usually used for stronger expressions as *навіть*, *й*/*і* (*even*): *й не мав на думці*. Anyway, you also can reply with [*міркування*](http://sum.in.ua/s/mirkuvannja) or [*визначення*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyznachennja):

> Я ще не визначився.
> I have not decided (yet).

> Я ще не обміркував.
> I still did not think enough.

Comment: Wouldn't "обміркував" be more closer in meaning to "to think it through", as in, by your example for "Я ще не обміркував", "I haven't thought it through yet"?

Comment: @MyOtherHead Close, but here is with a result, cause verb is [perfective](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect_in_Slavic_languages) via prefix _об_.

Answer (score 4):

You could try *точка зору* or *кут зору*, as in:

> Я не маю кута (точки) зору в цій справі
>   I don't have an opinion on this matter

If take dictionaries:

> [Кут зору](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46339&page=1462) — певний погляд на ті чи інші явища, певне розуміння чогось, певна позиція в чомусь
>
> [Точка (кут) зору](http://sum.in.ua/s/zir) — певний погляд на що-небудь, особисте ставлення до чогось
>
> ---
>
> (*literal*)
>   *Angle of sight* — a certain view of a particular phenomenon, a certain understanding of something, a certain position in something
>
> *Point/angle of sight* — a certain look at something, a personal attitude to something

Comment: Very good variation, maybe better than all my. But here is problem with declencion. I will try fix this. And I added some informations